# How configure cron jobs in cpanel x to run php script?

Tags: php, cron, cpanel, jobs

i've got a problem trying to configure cron jobs.
I've a site on byethost5 and it provides a cPanel X. 
I would like to run a php script every 5 minutes. This script (task.php) scans the database and change properly some coordinates of markers. The scripts works well because if I try to open it via browser it does what it has to. 
The problem is setting the 5 minutes loop. I thought i can use cron jobs, but i really don't manage to make them works.
Unfortunately, I have no shell, all I have is this option in the control panel under cron jobs menu:
[cron menu screen](http://easycaptures.com/fs/uploaded/720/1444687860.png)
As you can see, I can only add the path of the script located in the site. I did that, but it didn't work. It neither shows me errors or any kind of message.

Does anyone can help me please?
Thanks in advance.

edit 1

But the part of url in bold is already written, i can't modifiy it. I can insert the wget command even after it? Does have it sense a url like

```
http://example.byethost5.com/wget -O /dev/null http://www.test.com/cron.php
```

?

I didn't think so..

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
http://example.byethost5.com/ && wget -O /dev/null http://www.test.com/cron.php
```

Comment: But I can't edit the part in bold letters,so i can't add commands like wget before it

Comment: It says:
The command (&&_wget_-O_/dev/null_example.byethost5.com/folder/pagine/task.php) entered (makes http://example.byethost5.com/&&_wget_-O_/dev/null_example.byethost5.com/folder/pagine/task.php) does not appear valid.

An example of a valid path would be http://example.byethost5.com/myscripttocron.php ||&&_wget_-O_/dev/null_example.byethost5.com/folder/pagine/task.php||

Answer (score 1):

On the crontab command line put your command in this format:

```
/usr/bin/php -q /home/username/public_html/yourfilename.php
```